# Текст с ссылками через TextView

Tags: android, textview

Здравствуйте.

Проблема в следующем. Есть layout/main.xml, в нем TextView, естественно, весь текст через @string/. Так вот мне нужно, чтобы в этом тексте были ссылки на другие активити моего приложения. Изначально планировал сделать много TextView'ов, а ссылки делать через clickable="true" и onClick соответственно. И это в принципе работает. Но из-за разности разрешений андроида выглядит мерзопакостно. Так вот есть ли способ писать текст и сразу ссылки, как в обычном html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> выглядит мерзопакостно

Это потому, что вы не можете сделать нормальный Layout.

> есть ли способ

Есть, но он на много сложнее, чем сверстать правильный Layout. И такие задачи лучше делать именно через setOnClickListener()

*Если все же хочется сделать неправильно: то, о чем вы спрашивали, называется [**URL Scheme**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-scheme-on-android)*.